# How to remove wiggles from curves generated by MeshFunctions

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot a ruled surface using `ParametricPlot3D` so that the rulings are displayed on the plot.  Using the option `MeshFunctions` I've successfully done this several times.  However, for one ruled surface, shown below, some of the rulings are not straight, but rather have small wiggles in them.  Anyone know how to remove these?

```
d[α_] := {Piecewise[{{α, α <= 0}, {α, α > 0}}], 
          Piecewise[{{1/2 α^5, α <= 0}, {0, α > 0}}], 
          Piecewise[{{0, α <= 0}, {1/2 α^5, α > 0}}]};
t[α_] := d'[α]/Sqrt[d'[α].d'[α]]
b[α_] := {0, 
          Piecewise[{{0, α <= 0}, {1, α > 0}}], 
          Piecewise[{{-1, α <= 0}, {0, α > 0}}]};
p[α_] := Cross[b[α], t[α]];
κ[α_] := Sqrt[t'[α].t'[α]];
τ[α_] := -p[α].b'[α];
k[α_] := κ[α]*Piecewise[{{-1/2, α <= 0}, {Sqrt[3]/2, α > 0}}];
ϕ[α_] := ArcCos[k[α]/κ[α]];
θ[α_] := π/2;
m[α_] := Cos[ϕ[α]] p[α] + Sin[ϕ[α]] b[α];
g[α_] := Cos[θ[α]] d'[α] + Sin[θ[α]] m[α];
SD[α_, β_] = d[α] + β g[α];

PPTD = 
  ParametricPlot3D[
    SD[α, β], {α, -1, 1}, {β, -1/4, 1/4} , 
    PlotStyle -> LightBlue, 
    MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, α, β}, α]}, MaxRecursion -> 8, 
    Exclusions -> None];

PPd = 
  ParametricPlot3D[
    d[t], {t, -1, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
    PlotStyle -> Red, Exclusions -> None];

Show[PPTD, PPd, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

You can see the wiggles in the rulings on the left-hand side of this plot:

[image: You can see the wiggles in the rulings on the left-hand side of this plot.]

Comment: Setting `PlotPoints -> 100` in the first `ParametricPlot3D` seemed to work for me.

Comment: @MassDefect Simple enough.  Thank you!